# Unterschied zwischen "zu sehr" und "zu viel"

Tags: difference, usage

Die Phrasen *zu sehr* und *zu viel* sind beide praktisch ins Englische *too much* übersetzt. Es scheint mir aber, dass *zu sehr* wesentlich weniger benutzt wird als *zu viel*.

Was sind die Unterschiede zwischen die beiden Phrasen? Ist es nur eine stilistische Wahl, oder gibt es etwas mehr dazu?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generell gilt:

- *Sehr* bemisst die Intensität. Englisch: *very.*
- *Viel* bemisst die Menge. Englisch: *much.*
- *Viele/vieler/vieles* bemessen die Anzahl. Englisch: *many.*

Daraus folgt, dass man in vielen Fällen sowieso nur eines der beiden nutzen kann, zum Beispiel:

> Ich habe zu viel gegessen.
>   Es ist zu viel passiert (als dass ich Dir alles erzählen könnte).
>
> Ich habe es mir zu sehr gewünscht (und habe dadurch alles andere vernachlässigt).

Häufig sind auch beide Varianten möglich, ohne dass sich die Bedeutung ändert:

> Ich habe zu sehr gelitten.
>   Ich habe zu viel gelitten.

Andererseits gibt es auch Fälle, in denen kleine Unterschiede bestehen:

> Ich war zu sehr abgelenkt, um die Explosion zu hören.
>   Ich war zu viel abgelenkt, sodass ich garn nicht zum Arbeiten kam.

Im ersten Fall ist die Ablenkung sehr intensiv, nämlich zum Zeitpunkt der Explosion. Im zweiten Fall ist die Ablenkung nicht unbedingt intensiv, aber dauerhaft.

> Es regnet zu viel.
>   Es regnet zu sehr.
>   Es regnet zu oft.

Im ersten Fall geht es um die Gesamtniederschlagsmenge (in einem Zeitintervall), im zweiten Fall um Regenintensität (zu einem Zeitpunkt) und im dritten Fall um die Regenhäufigkeit.

---

Dass *zu sehr* seltener benutzt wird, liegt vermutlich daran, dass es weniger passende Einsatzmöglichkeiten gibt und man es häufig durch ein anderes Wort ersetzen kann, was bevorzugt wird. Dieses Wort ist meistens *stark.* Zum Beispiel:

> Es regnet zu sehr. → Es regnet zu stark.
>   Ich habe es mir zu sehr gewünscht. → Ich habe es mir zu stark gewünscht.
>   Es gefiel mir zu sehr (als dass ich es hätte ignorieren können). → Es gefiel mir zu gut.

Comment: Deine Unterscheidung zwischen "zu viel" und "zu oft" ist präzise, aber ich glaube, daß umgangssprachlich oft auch ersteres benutzt wird, wenn letzteres gemeint ist. Insbesondere bei Regen: Zwei Wochen immer wieder einsetzender Nieselregen wird bei vielen eher ein "es regnet zu viel" hervorrufen als ein einzelner Wolkenbruch mit der Durchschnittsregenmenge eines ganzen Monats.

Answer (score 2):

Alle Beispiele enthalten "zu viel" und "zu sehr". Das ist insgesamt keine ausreichende Erklärung. 
"viel" steht für Quantität: Er hat viel Geld.
"sehr" steht für Qualität:  Er ist sehr reich.

Comment: Ein schöner Ansatz, es kurz zu erklären. Aber wie erklärst du dann "Er hat sehr viel Geld"? Drückt "sehr" hier eine Qualität von "viel" aus?

Comment: Wilkommen! Ich habe leider keine Ahnung, worauf sich die ersten beiden Sätze beziehen.

Comment: @CarstenS Ich denke, dass die ersten 2 Sätze sich auf [die Antwort von Wrzlprmft](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/17702/19763) beziehen.

Comment: @FabioTurati, Danke, ich hatte diese Antwort nur in der Review-Queue gesehen. Regina: Diese Website sieht ein Frage-und-Antwort-Format vor, keine Diskussion.