# Das hängt viel/sehr vom Kontext ab

Tags: word-choice, usage

> Das hängt ___ vom Kontext ab.
>
> (a) viel
>
> (b) sehr

Ich habe die Antwort [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17699/unterschied-zwischen-zu-sehr-und-zu-viel) gelesen, und trotzdem bin ich mir mit diesem Satz nicht sicher. Ich würde raten, dass nur **viel** passt, weil es hier nicht um die Intensität, sondern um die Menge geht. Ist das richtig?

Comment: Auch wenn es für manche nicht schön klingen mag, kann man ["hängt sehr viel vom.Kontext ab"](https://books.google.de/books?id=2YpWLC5rrCUC&pg=PT46&lpg=PT46&dq="sehr+viel+vom+kontext"&source=bl&ots=vQsBI2EDNr&sig=H-AjPFHKI27Fr7oZ-9EYnum3CPs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0NSmVIe_IoLlO8OGgZgN&redir_esc=y) sagen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In deinem Beispielsatz funktioniert nur *sehr*. Die Verwendung von *viel* ist in dem Beispiel mindestens ungewohnt, wenn nicht gar falsch. Allgemein gilt, dass man

> [Subjekt] hängt sehr von etwas ab

sagt, jedoch nicht

> [Subjekt] hängt viel von etwas ab

Angemerkt sei, dass ich jegliche Beispiele, die Wrzlprmft mit *viel* formuliert hat, als teils sogar äußerst unnatürlich empfinde. Eine Google-Suche hat aber gezeigt, dass vereinzelt solche Formulierungen tatsächlich verwendet werden.

Allerdings täuscht hier einem eine schlichte Internetsuche auch schnell etwas vor. Wenn man die Suche nicht sauber formuliert, mischt sich eine leicht andere Form unter die Suchergebnisse.

> Es hängt viel von … ab
>   Viel hängt von … ab

Hierbei ist das "es" im ersten Satz kein richtiges Subjekt, sondern nur ein Art Platzhalter (siehe [Expletivum](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expletivum)). In diesem Konstrukt ist *viel* nicht nur akzeptabel, sondern wird auch gleichermaßen häufig verwendet wie *sehr*.

Festzuhalten ist also:

- Hängt ein "konkretes Subjekt" von etwas ab, so hängt es *sehr*, *stark*, [hier beliebiges anderes Adverb] ab, jedoch nicht *viel*.
- Etwas Unspezifiziertes kann aber sehr wohl *viel* von etwas abhängen. Dabei handelt es sich aber nicht um ein Adverb, sondern um ein Zahlwort. Man kann auch *vieles* verwenden.

Beispiele:

> In dieser Phase hängt viel von Europa ab. <sup>[SPIEGEL](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/revolution-in-tunesien-in-dieser-phase-haengt-viel-von-europa-ab-a-741417.html)</sup>
>   Ich glaube, es hängt viel davon ab, was eine Frau in ihnen sehen möchte. <sup>[ZEIT](http://www.zeit.de/2010/08/Traum-Christian-Louboutin)</sup>
>   Außerdem hängt viel davon ab, wie sich der frühere Premierminister Mahathir Mohamad verhält. <sup>[FAZ](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/ausland/malaysia-schwieriges-zusammenleben-11780402.html)</sup>
>   Vieles hängt von dem Ausgang der nächsten Wahlen des Studentenparlaments ab. <sup>[ZEIT](http://www.zeit.de/1965/31/die-hoffentlich-produktive-unruhe/seite-3)</sup>

<sub>Nur im zweiten Satz kann auch *sehr* verwendet werden, da dort sowohl das Zahlwort als auch ein Adverb grammatikalisch Sinn ergibt.</sub>

Außerdem sprechen die Zahlen für Google-Hits eine sehr deutliche Sprache:

- ~5 % der Suchergebnisse für "hängt viel von" sind "das hängt viel von"
- ~8 % der Suchergebnisse für "hängt viel davon ab" sind "das hängt viel davon ab"
- ~20 % der Suchergebnisse für "hängt sehr von" sind "das hängt sehr von"
- ~30 % der Suchergebnisse für "hängt sehr davon ab" sind "das hängt sehr davon ab"

Um einer Fehlinterpretation vorzubeugen: Diese Statistik zeigt nicht, dass bei der Verwendung von *sehr* das Wort *das* häufiger verwendet wird. Das Pronomen *das* ist de facto der universelle Platzhalter für ein zuvor genanntes konkretes Subjekt. Folglich zeigt die Statistik, dass bei der Verwendung eines konkreten Subjekts anschließend gängigerweise *sehr* verwendet; nicht jedoch *viel*.

Der Vollständigkeit halber, hier die Zahlen für die Verwendung von "es":

- 22,5 % für "es hängt viel von"
- 11 % für "es hängt viel davon ab"
- 13 % für "es hängt sehr von"
- 21,5 % für "es hängt sehr davon ab"

Hier ist ein wesentlich ausgeglicheneres Verhältnis zu sehen.

Hier nochmal zusammengefasst die gängigsten Formen:

> Es hängt viel von … ab.
>   Es hängt sehr davon ab.
>   Das hängt sehr von … ab.

Answer (score 2):

Wenn man *viel* verwenden möchte (da spricht nichts dagegen, ich sehe da auch keine stehende Wendung), muss der Satz lauten:

> Viel hängt vom Kontext ab.

Das *sehr* alleine finde ich seltsam. Ich würde schreiben:

> Das hängt sehr **stark** vom Kontext ab.

Comment: Natürlich kann man sagen "Viel hängt vom Kontext ab", aber "_Das_ hängt viel vom Kontext ab" kann man mE nicht sagen. Ich gebe Dir recht, dass eine Wendung mit "stark" wahrscheinlich besser wäre, aber "sehr" allein ist jdf nicht falsch.

Comment: Man muss den Satz nicht mal umstellen. Ich würde beinah behaupten, dass man im Originalsatz nur einen Buchstaben weglassen muss, um "viel" benutzen zu können: "Da hängt viel vom Kontext ab". Natürlich ändert sich hier die Bedeutung und idiomatisch erscheint es mir auch nicht. Außerdem kann man "sehr" dann nicht mehr verwenden. Trotzdem OK, denke ich.

Answer (score 1):

Ich würde dies als einen Fall einstufen, in dem sowohl *sehr* als auch *viel* möglich sind, allerdings mit gewissen Unterschieden in der Bedeutung bzw. Anwendbarkeit.

*Sehr* passt meines Erachtens alleinig, wenn es eine einzelne Abhängigkeit geht, zu der **ein** Zusammenhang besteht, und die Intensität dieses Zusammenhangs quantifiziert wird, z. B.:

> Wann ich ankomme, hängt sehr davon ab, wann ich losfahre.
> Wann ich ankomme, hängt kaum davon ab, wann ich losfahre.
>
> Ob ich ein Auto mag, hängt sehr von seiner Farbe ab.
> Ob ich ein Auto mag, hängt kaum von seiner Farbe ab.

Hier würde ich *viel* oder *wenig* nicht verwenden. (Eine Internet-Suche bestätigt dies insofern, dass die Ergebnisse für `"Das hängt viel [da]von"` nicht hierunter fallen, sondern eher unter das Folgende.)

Wenn jedoch die Abhängigkeit von etwas beschrieben wird, das in Wirklichkeit eine Anhäufung von Einzelaspekten ist, von denen etwas abhängen kann, z. B. *der Kontext* oder *die geopolitische Lage,* kann meines Erachtens durchaus auch *viel* verwendet werden (auch wenn ich es selbst eher *stark* oder *sehr* nutzen würde):

> Ob dieser Satz verständlich ist, hängt viel vom Kontext ab.
> Ob dieser Satz verständlich ist, hängt sehr vom Kontext ab.
> Ob dieser Satz verständlich ist, hängt stark vom Kontext ab.
>
> Ob das Bruttoinlandsprodukt nächstes Jahr steigen wird, hängt viel von der geopolitischen Lage ab.
> Ob das Bruttoinlandsprodukt nächstes Jahr steigen wird, hängt sehr von der geopolitischen Lage ab.
> Ob das Bruttoinlandsprodukt nächstes Jahr steigen wird, hängt stark von der geopolitischen Lage ab.

Dasselbe gilt, wenn es mehrere Wege der Abhängigkeit gibt (die man also gewissermaßen zählen kann):

> [Nach Beschreibung diverser Zusammenhänge:]
> Fazit: Ob Angela Merkel nach 2017 Kanzlerin bleibt, hängt viel davon ab, ob Deutschland 2016 Fußballeuropameister wird.
> *(analog mit* sehr *und* stark)

Schließlich kann noch das Abhängende in Wirklichkeit eine Anhäufung von Aspekten sein:

> Die geopolitische Lage hängt viel vom Dienstalter des US-Präsidenten ab.
> Die geopolitische Lage hängt sehr vom Dienstalter des US-Präsidenten ab.
> Die geopolitische Lage hängt stark vom Dienstalter des US-Präsidenten ab.

---

Umgekehrt, könnte man in gewissen Fällen eine Bedeutungsnuance zwischen *sehr/stark* und *viel* sehen:

> Ob dieses Wort angemessen ist, hängt viel vom Kontext ab.
> Ob dieses Wort angemessen ist, hängt sehr vom Kontext ab.

Die Verwendung von *viel* würde hier implizieren, dass es viele Unteraspekte des Kontexts gebe, die die Angemessenheit des Worts beeinflussen (und die Abhängigkeit also eine komplexe ist). Hingegen würde *sehr* implizieren, dass nur zu einem Aspekt des Kontexts eine Abhängigkeit bestehe, welche aber stark sei. (Dies ist wohlgemerkt mit Vorsicht zu genießen, da es voraussetzt, dass sich der Urheber dieser Zeilen entsprechende Gedanken macht.)

---

Zu allem Überfluss ist in den allermeisten Fällen die Unterscheidung zwischen einer starken Abhängigkeit oder mehreren Abhängigkeiten eine Frage der persönlichen Interpretation, z. B.:

> Ob ich ein Lied mag, hängt [stark/sehr/viel] von der Stimme des Sängers ab.

Hier kann ich die Stimme als eine einzelne Ursache interpretieren, aber auch als Anhäufung von Ursachen, indem ich sie in verschiedene Aspekte wie Volumen, Rauheit, Höhe, usw. unterteile.

---

Persönlich halte ich *stark* für die stilistisch beste Wahl und es ist auch gemäß [dieses Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(h%C3%A4ngt+stark+davon)+%2B+(h%C3%A4ngt+stark+von)%2C(h%C3%A4ngt+sehr+davon)+%2B+(h%C3%A4ngt+sehr+von)%2C(h%C3%A4ngt+viel+davon)+%2B+(h%C3%A4ngt+viel+von)&year_start=1800&year_end=2014&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28h%C3%A4ngt%20stark%20davon%29%20%2B%20%28h%C3%A4ngt%20stark%20von%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28h%C3%A4ngt%20sehr%20davon%29%20%2B%20%28h%C3%A4ngt%20sehr%20von%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28h%C3%A4ngt%20viel%20davon%29%20%2B%20%28h%C3%A4ngt%20viel%20von%29%3B%2Cc0) mittlerweile die dominierende Variante.

Comment: Siehe auch die entsprechenden Ngrams für "stark/sehr/viel auf etw. ankommen": http://tinyurl.com/on7zc99

Answer (score 1):

Bei der Frage des Kontextes muss es **sehr** heißen.

> Es hängt sehr vom Kontext ab, ob *sehr* oder *viel* richtig ist.

Das bedeutet, dass die Abhängigkeit stark ist.

> Es hängt viel davon ab ...

ist dagegen eine quantitative Aussage, bei der mehrere Sachen von einem Sachverhalt  abhängen, etwa

> Es hängt viel vom Klassenerhalt ab, etwa ob Spieler u. Trainer gehalten werden können, ob man einen zahlungskräftigen Sponsor findet, ob das Stadion weiter ausgebaut werden kann und einiges mehr.

Answer (score 0):

Nein, es passt nur *sehr*. Warum? Ich nehme an, dass es eine stehende Wendung ist.

Comment: Das ist keine stehende Wendung. Ich kann da auch "extrem", "stark", "ungemein", "regelrecht", "krass", ... und noch gefühlt 20.000 andere Wörter einsetzen und der Satz ist absolut in Ordnung. Die Verwendung von "viel" geht in dem Satz so wie er da steht jedoch schlicht nicht.

Comment: Naja, _(sehr) abhängen von_ ist dann aber doch etwas verbreiteter als _regelrecht_, _krass_ oder _ungemein_. Im Ergebnis sind wir uns aber wohl einig.

Comment: @Em1.. geht nicht gibt's nicht. https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1DVCJ_enDE430DE443&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=%22das%20h%C3%A4ngt%20viel%20von%20%22  bitte begründen warum es nicht gehen soll, wenn es doch offensichtlich in Zeitungen gemacht wird.

Comment: und um auch "davon" noch abzudecken... https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1DVCJ_enDE430DE443&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=%22das+h%C3%A4ngt+viel+davon+%22   ... Angesichts der Tatsache,d ass es durchaus in Büchern und Zeitungen zu finden ist, halte ich ein schlichtes "es geht nur sehr" für unangemessen. Es sollte vielmehr heißen, dass "sehr" die stilistisch bessere Wahl ist, und warum.

Comment: Ich habe mal wie @Emanuel mit google rumgespielt: ngram sagt, dass "das hängt viel" mal um 1900 bis 1950 und dann wieder seit 1990 häufiger vorkommt. Ich weiß allerdings nicht, wie aussagekräftig das ist: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=das+h%C3%A4ngt+viel&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=7&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cdas%20h%C3%A4ngt%20viel%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdas%20h%C3%A4ngt%20viel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDas%20h%C3%A4ngt%20viel%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score -1):

Ich würde sagen

> Das hängt weitgehend vom Kontext ab.

Comment: beantwortet irgendwie nicht so wirklich die Frage...

Comment: Das Wort weitgehend existiert nicht mal in den Auswahlmöglichkeiten :D